# Plugin to list active plugins across networked sites

Tags: plugins, multisite, network-admin

I guess the title of this question is not clear. I'm asking for a plugin, which only superadmins can use, that shows which (or, at least, how many) blogs use each plugin installed on the network.

I've searched a lot for this, but found nothing. Is anybody who knows any such plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like: [**Active Plugins**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/active-plugins-on-multisite/) which is a plugin that Generates a list of plugins that are currently in use and Does not include primary blog, network activated plugins, or plugins with 0 users.